# How to implement the Karplus-Strong algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, audio, simulation

I've looked all over the place and I can't seem to find an example of a simple Java program that uses the Karplus-Strong algorithm which is strange because I think it's supposed to be a classic coding exercise. The equation is y[n] = x[n] + 0.5 * (y[n-N] + y[n-(N+1)]). It is supposed to give a soundwave that simulates a guitar string being plucked. So far I have the following code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws LineUnavailableException {
        int rate = 44100;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(rate, 8, 1, false, true);
        SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        sdl.open();
        sdl.start();

        for(int i = 1; i < rate; i++) {
            buffer[0] = (byte) (...);
            sdl.write(buffer, 0, 1);
        }   
    }   

}
```

How would I use the equation to create an array of bytes that I can plug into my code?

Comment: Can I see your own implementation first, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an array of PCM values which you will use to calculate the sound wave values, and an array of bytes which will hold the values to be written to the `SourceDataLine`.

The size of the PCM array is set to the period of the wave you are creating. So, if you want to make an A 440, the period (based on a sample rate of 44100fps) would be 100 (a tad sharp of 440).

The first step is to fill the PCM array with random numbers (floats suffice, ranging within -1 to 1).
Then loop through the following two steps (starting with the second step):

- Calculate the next set of PCM values based on the formula you cited.
- Convert the PCM buffer values to bytes per your audio format and append it to the byte array that will be written to the `SourceDataLine`.

When the byte buffer for the `SourceDataLine` is full, write the buffer and start refilling it for the next write operation.

There is an [article here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/sound/karplusstrong.html) that also describes some refinements to the algorithm. Details on converting the PCM to bytes per the audio format have been covered in other posts.

Following is a quick and dirty implementation. The code only plays a 200-pcm note. Obviously one would want to rewrite this to make it work for other notes. But it does show the algorithm in action and it does play.

```
public class KarplusStrongTone {

    float[] pcmArray;
    SourceDataLine sdl; 
    int period = 200;
    int sdlIdx = 0; 
    byte sdlBuffer[] = new byte[4000];


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
    IOException, InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException {

        KarplusStrongTone kst = new KarplusStrongTone();
        kst.initializePCMArray();
        kst.makeOutputLine();
        kst.play();
    }   

    private void initializePCMArray()
    {
        pcmArray = new float[period];
        for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) pcmArray[i] = (float)(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    }

    private void makeOutputLine() throws LineUnavailableException {

        AudioFormat audioFmt = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 
                44100, 16, 1, 2, 44100, false);

        Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFmt);
        sdl = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        sdl.open();
        sdl.start();    
    }


    private void play()
    {
        int countIterations = 0;
        float localMax = 1;

        while (localMax > 0.00001f)
        {
            localMax = 0;
            for (int i = period - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                pcmArray[i] = (pcmArray[i] + pcmArray[i-1])/2;
                localMax = Math.max(Math.abs(pcmArray[i]), localMax);
            }
            pcmArray[0] = pcmArray[0]/2;

            countIterations++; // just curious how long while runs

            ship(pcmArray);

        }       
        System.out.println("Iterations = " + countIterations);
    }

    private void ship(float[] pcm)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
        {
            int audioVal = (int)(pcm[i] * 32767);
            sdlBuffer[sdlIdx + i * 2] = (byte)audioVal;
            sdlBuffer[sdlIdx + (i * 2) + 1] = (byte)(audioVal >> 8);
        }
        sdlIdx += (period * 2);

        if (sdlIdx == 4000)
        {
            sdl.write(sdlBuffer, 0, 4000);
            sdlIdx = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do that part, it's the equation, I'm having trouble with. I have tried: buffer[0] = (byte) (0.5*(randomArray[i-1]+randomArray[i])); but I only hear static.

Comment: When you average the adjacent PCM values of your initial period (in your randomArray[]), over multiple iterations the entire array of values approaches 0. There is no randomArray[-1] element, by definition, so the value 0 is used for that in the calculation algorithm. The resulting buff[] becomes the next randomArray[]. Does that help? In other words, the "filtering" action of the calculation is a simple box filter of 2 elements.\